# What is the purpose of the empty functions in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Could you please tell me why does Wordpress has some php files that contains empty functions?

I mean such as `/wp-admin/load-scripts.php` or `/wp-admin/load-styles.php`.

Comment: Backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load-scripts.php` and `load-styles.php` are called directly with `<script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags in the admin dashboard. Their purpose is to concatenate a bunch of individual files into one HTTP request on-the-fly.

For performance, they don't bootstrap WordPress by calling `wp-load.php`. Instead, they use those empty functions to [stub out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub) core parts of the WordPress API (translation and filters) that may be called by some of the other code they load. That way, nothing crashes when it tries to call a function that isn't there.